# Call azure ad-protected API from powershell with username/password

Tags: azure, powershell, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD-protected web api. 
My javascript sends a callback-url where the users access-token is sent to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my_tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token/?redirect_uri={my_url}&...
```

Now I want to access my api using powershell and for that reason I would like to just have the token as a response. I have tried this [resource owner password credential-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) with the code below, but it just says that the username or password is incorrect...(I use same for manual login)

```
   $creds =  @{
        client_id = $clientId
        username = $username
        password = $password
        grant_type = "password"
        scope="User.Read" 
    }

$headers = @{        
    "Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
Invoke-RestMethod $authUrl -Method Post -Body $creds -Headers $headers;
```

So, in short, I want to login using username and password with powershell, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce your issue, please double check your username and password.

Or you can try my working sample, and if you want to get the toekn from your own api, the `scope` should be `{Application ID URI or Application ID}/User.Read`, if you use `scope="User.Read"`, it represents the MS Graph API by default.

**Sample**:

```
 $authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token/"

 $clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 $username = "xxxxxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
 $password = "xxxxxx"

   $creds =  @{
        client_id = $clientId
        username = $username
        password = $password
        grant_type = "password"
        scope="{Application ID URI or Application ID}/User.Read" 
    }

$headers = @{        
    "Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
Invoke-RestMethod $authUrl -Method Post -Body $creds -Headers $headers
```

[image]

**Update:**

When using resource owner password credential flow, please note the important things below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still get invalid username or pwd.Ive tested with two different accounts, one of them is now locked out so I cant test to much more until I get it unlocked. I get back after that and some more tries

Comment: @Cowborg Does your user account enable the MFA? If users need to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to log in to the application, they will be blocked instead.

Comment: @Cowborg Take a look at the update in my reply, there are some important things when you using this flow.

Comment: Thanks!I dont understand bullet 2. What accounts can be used then?

Comment: @Cowborg It may be the work account/school account. You can navigate to the Azure AD in the portal -> Users -> New user, create a new user to test.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and I have upvoted it, but I cant accept it until its solved. Ill be happy to gve you the credits if this helps, but it would be misleading to others if I marked it as solved/accepted

Comment: @Cowborg Why will it mislead others?

Comment: Because my problem is not solved, so if another person have this problem in the future, the "accepted" answer will not help that person

Comment: @Cowborg If your account belongs the accounts which could not use ROPC flow, I think it is related to you, my answer is correct, so it is worth accepting.

Comment: As I said, I will accept it when I can confirm this.

Comment: @Cowborg Well, you could create a new user as I mentioned above to test, wait for you.

Comment: Hello Joy. I dont have admin access to our Azure. I have  case at our IT-dept. I'll keep you posted

Comment: @Cowborg Hi, have you got it now?

Comment: No :(, I wish our IT-department was as eager as you t solve this problem...

Comment: @Cowborg Ahhhh, yes, I am eager for the truth of the matter. Maybe you can also remind them.:-)